# Input checkbox didn't work what I expected

Tags: reactjs

I tried to make an input checkbox when I click the input checkbox, it should be displayed a check image like this.
[image]

However, it didn't show the checkbox and I am not sure how to check that the input box was checked or not. Could you help me with what part do I missed and where is something wrong?
I really appreciate your help!

This is CSS inputl and label part

```
.colors {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        span {
          margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .colorLists {
          margin-left: 10px;
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          .colorLayout {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            position: relative;
            width: 33%;
            height: 80px;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            .checkboxLabel {
              background-color: beige;
              border: 1px solid #ccc;
              border-radius: 50%;
              cursor: pointer;
              height: 28px;
              left: 0;
              position: absolute;
              top: 40;
              width: 28px;
              &:after {
                border: 2px solid #fff;
                border-top: none;
                border-right: none;
                content: '';
                height: 6px;
                left: 7px;
                opacity: 0;
                position: absolute;
                top: 8px;
                transform: rotate(-45deg);
                width: 12px;
                // opacity: 0.2;
              }
            }
            input[type='checkbox'] {
              visibility: hidden;
            }
            input[type='checkbox']:checked {
              & + label {
                background-color: beige;
                border-color: beige;
                &:after {
                  opacity: 1;
                }
              }
            }

            .productColor {
              margin-top: 70px;
              font-size: 13px;
              margin-right: 21px;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      .sizes {
        .HorizontalLine {
          margin-top: 25px;
        }

        .span {
        }

        .sizeLists {
          margin-top: 20px;
          margin-bottom: 20px;

          button {
            margin: 5px;
            width: 44px;
            height: 32px;
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid silver;
            border-radius: 15%;
          }
        }
      }
```

This is js part

```
<div className="colors">
              <span>색상</span>
              <ul className="colorLists">
                {COLOR_LISTS.map((color, idx) => {
                  return (
                    <li className="colorLayout" key={idx}>
                      <input type="checkbox" />
                      <label
                        className="checkboxLabel"
                        for="checkbox"
                        style={{ backgroundColor: color.colorProps }}
                      />
                      <span className="productColor">{color.color_name}</span>
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react you have to set the `htmlFor` property for the label instead of `for`.
The value should be the same as the `id` from the input.
Then you can add a `value` property for the input which is used for adding/removing the item in the list of selected items.
For this purpose a `handleChange` function can be defined.

```
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

  function handleChange(e) {
    let newSelected = [];
    if (selectedItems.includes(e.target.value)) {
      newSelected = selectedItems.filter((item) => item !== e.target.value);
    } else {
      newSelected = [...selectedItems, e.target.value];
    }
    setSelectedItems(newSelected);
  }

  return (
    <div className="colors">
      <span>색상</span>
      <ul className="colorLists">
        {COLOR_LISTS.map((color, idx) => {
          return (
            <li className="colorLayout" key={idx}>
              <input
                onChange={handleChange}
                type="checkbox"
                id={idx}
                value={color.color_name}
                checked={selectedItems.includes(color.color_name)}
              />
              <label
                className="checkboxLabel"
                htmlFor={idx}
                style={{ backgroundColor: color.colorProps }}
              />
              <span className="productColor">{color.color_name}</span>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

EDIT: Since you are using a class component it can be rewrittenlike this:

```
export default class CheckboxListComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selectedItems: [] };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    let newSelected = [];
    if (this.state.selectedItems.includes(e.target.value)) {
      newSelected = this.state.selectedItems.filter(
        (item) => item !== e.target.value
      );
    } else {
      newSelected = [...this.state.selectedItems, e.target.value];
    }
    this.setState({ selectedItems: newSelected });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="colors">
        <span>색상</span>
        <ul className="colorLists">
          {COLOR_LISTS.map((color, idx) => {
            return (
              <li className="colorLayout" key={idx}>
                <input
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  type="checkbox"
                  id={idx}
                  value={color.color_name}
                  checked={this.state.selectedItems.includes(color.color_name)}
                />
                <label
                  className="checkboxLabel"
                  htmlFor={idx}
                  style={{ backgroundColor: color.colorProps }}
                />
                <span className="productColor">{color.color_name}</span>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed explaination! I tried to understand what you said and follow up your code but even I import "import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';" I got this error message " React Hook "useState" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function" Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: I have edited the answer with an example for a class component.
For more information about handling events see also: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: I really appreciate your help... I didn't expect a fully detailed and runnable answer... I am struggling with this issue for two days. Due to this issue, I didn't do the other things that I want to do. I tried to understand this code one by one at this moment! I really appreciate! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you don't mind can I ask why did you wrrite "this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);". Furthermore, it doesn't work when I erase this in bind(this) but it works even though I erase props.

Answer (score 1):

You must tell react that your input is checked so that your CSS will apply it. selected ids must be kept in a place for future existence check. in the following code, I named this array selecetedIdx.
You also need to add idx on selection(via onChange event handler) or wrap them all in form and add them via extra dom attribute.

```
class Main extends Component {
  // initialize selectedIdx with [] in your state (esp constructor)
  // e.g. this.state = {/* rest of state, */ selectedIdx: []}

render() {
 return (
{COLOR_LISTS.map((color, idx) => {
  return (
    // ...
    <input 
      type="checkbox" 
      checked={selectedIdx.includes(idx)} 
      onChange={() => this.setState(state => ({
       selectedIdx: [...state.selectedIdx, idx]
      }))}
    />
   // ...
  )}
 )
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for helping me out! If you don't mind, can I ask what the selectedIdx do? and How do I declare it?

Comment: It is simple state, of you application if you can use function component and react hook, it is simple as `const [selectedIdx, setSelectedIdx] = useState([])`

Comment: I just get started studying react.js for 2 weeks, so pretty hard what do you mean but thank you for trying to help me out

Comment: are you using a class base component those `class App extends from React.Components` or a simple function?

Comment: I am using export class Main extends Component  this one! I am not sure answering the right thing..

Comment: oh and I import "import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';" I got this error message " React Hook "useState" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function" Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: Hooks are not compatible with the class, I will update the question to support it in a breif

Answer (score 0):

Your checkbox element needs `name` and `value` properties and would normally be a child of the `<form>` element.